# Can't scroll down in some area

Tags: support, scrolling

*I'm using Window 7 Professional service pack 1, 64bit*

I can't scroll down window when a mouse has hovering in the red area. (Happening at some time)

[image]

Happened in a questions page too.

[image]

Same to Firefox 11.0 , IE8 and Google Chrome 18.0.1025.152 m

Is it a bug?

Comment: That's odd. No repro in latest Chrome on Win7 64 (although Home Premium).

Comment: Well.Too bad, I found it! 

Because of a Facebook Messenger stay behind in that area. (In minimize mode) **Should I delete this question?**

Comment: No, post an answer. Someone else who uses Facebook's buggy software might have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. 
The problem was due to Facebook Messenger`*` lingering in that area of the screen.

`*`Version 2.0.4478.0

In minimize mode, it shows the position, see image:

[image: screen shot of offending Facebook Messenger pop-up]

This **only** happened after clicking on the close button *(it doesn't always happen, but many times it does)*.

If I click on the minimize button, instead of the close button, it is fine. All is well.

Comment: Again, facebook shows its true evil nature.

Comment: Thank you. I can't even imagine how they achieve this...